# Python enter key press, keyboard module

Tags: python, keyboard-python

When using python with the keyboard module is there a way I can use enter to execute something within a program?

Comment: please be more precise, show what you've tried, or be more precise about your environment

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey "enter" is the name of the enter key in there

Comment: I use "enter" within `keyboard.is_pressed("enter")` and it never works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyboard.add_hotkey` to call the `foobar` function when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```py
import keyboard

def foobar():
    print("foo bar") 

keyboard.add_hotkey("enter", foobar)
keyboard.wait()
```

Source from the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey).